# How do I parse this illogical date string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, parsing

I have a date time string `September 30, 2017 @ 11:23 am`, which is parsable in chrome using:

```
var end = new Date("September 30, 2017 @ 11:23 am");
```

But in firefox it gives `invalid date` error. How do I parse it in Firefox?

Comment: Parsing date/time strings is notoriously unreliable because there are so many different formats and most date APIs simply don't bother supporting more than a few standardized formats. You probably need to write your own parsing function or use a library that supports this particular format.

Comment: Are you planning to parse *only this* format? You can use things like regular expression to extract out the `September` part, `30`, `2017` and `11:23 am`. However, if you are trying to parse general date string that may come in many different format you will need a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org)

> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

**Solution:** You can simply remove `@` from the stirng. using `replace` method or any other way.

***Ex:***

```js
var d = "September 30, 2017 @ 11:23 am"
var end = new Date(d.replace("@",""));

console.log(end)
```

Comment: If you reference MDN, you should link to the [*relevant part*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), where it says: "***parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.***".

Comment: @mega6382 You're welcome.

Comment: @RobG Thank you. Updated!.

Answer (score -1):

In both Firefox and chrome, removing the `@` works. you could replace the `@` symbol.

```
let date = 'September 30, 2017 @ 11:23 am'
new Date(date.replace('@', ''))
```